# Nothing from a table shows up in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have several table created by recently i can get anything to come from one of them.

The table is called REP and i'm currently using Live SQL from Oracle as i'm quite new to SQL

The select command i'm trying to use.:

`select * from REP`

I go to my schema and the table is definitely there. No commands for this table work.:
[image: I go to my schema and the table is definitely there. No commands for this table work.]

If anyone could help i'd very much appreciate it. Don't be too hard on me i'm quite new to SQL.

Comment: Show us the insert statements you used to put data into the table.

Comment: are you sure that have also data in the table because normally it must work.

Comment: please don't place images of statements - only code is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is empty. First insert the values into this table via 
`INSERT INTO REP VALUES(...)` 
and 
then use your query `Select * from rep`

As in your image, the table is there thats the ddl view meaning table's structure not data i.e. you have only columns but no data.

Comment: Okay, i understand now. I believed that i had data in the table because i put some in earlier. I'll go ahead and put the values in. I wonder why that happened?

Comment: I entered in my values and now the table is showing. Thanks for the help.